# how useful is Cling C++ JIT interpreter developed at CERN?

Tags: clang, cling

I recently watched great google talks speech about Cling - C++ language interpreter. But I wonder if anyone except people at CERN (where it is developed) are using Cling, and how good it is from non-collider-physics-scientist point of view, can you write desktop apps with it?

Comment: In theory, yes, you can run any sort of code in it. Useful... I suppose it is, but depends on your point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some videos of uses cases different from the High Energy Physics: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cling+c%2B%2B (I think first couple are the relevant ones)

Answer (score 3):

It has the potential to be very useful, but it is very young.  There is no documentation that I could find, no dedicated mailing list, no online tutorials.  I was able to get small toy code to run, but couldn't figure out how to use it productively on a large library yet.

Answer (score 0):

Cling project is well established one. You can find more information in their official website [cling](https://root.cern.ch/cling). They also have a [forum](https://root-forum.cern.ch)
Thanks